# Wrong arguments to vulkan graphics pipeline despite signature matching examples and source code

Tags: c++, graphics, compiler-errors, gpu, vulkan

So I have these 2 lines of code that refuse to compile:

```
vk::GraphicsPipelineCreateInfo pipeline_info();
device.createGraphicsPipeline({}, pipeline_info);
```

According to [this example](https://github.com/dokipen3d/vulkanHppMinimalExample/blob/master/main.cpp) this should work. However the compiler complains:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘vk::Device::createGraphicsPipeline(<brace-enclosed initializer list>, vk::GraphicsPipelineCreateInfo (&)())’
 device.createGraphicsPipeline({}, pipeline_info);
```

I don;t understand why this doesn't work, modifying the call to use unique initialization makes no difference.

Comment: Which compiler are  you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the most-vexing parse:

```
vk::GraphicsPipelineCreateInfo pipeline_info();
```

You are declaring a function, not an object!

See e.g. [My attempt at value initialization is interpreted as a function declaration, and why doesn't A a(()); solve it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/my-attempt-at-value-initialization-is-interpreted-as-a-function-declaration-and)

Comment: You should flag a post as a duplicate rather than posting an answer with a link to another question